# Magento (newbie query): how can I display product specification attributes?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to extract the Brand and other attributes within the "Specification" under "Product Information" (Catalog -> Manage Products - then select a product).

I can get the product name by doing the following:

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
```

I need something similar to display a Specification attribute on the front end.

How do I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me :

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$guarantee = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($_product->getId(), 'spec_guarantee', 1); // 1 is the store id

echo $guarantee;
// outputs:
// 2 Years Manufacturers Guarantee
```

Answer (score 0):

In magento 1.9 I used the following code to display a custom attribute.

```
<?php $_product->getData('takealotlink'); ?>
```

However to make sure it displays in the front-end you also have to set the correct property from manage attributes.

[image]

The property to set in Front-end properties is "Used in product listing". See arrow below.

[image]